# GraniteDS - Externalized services-config file

Tags: apache-flex, graniteds

i'm looking for a way to externalize the configuration file, *services-config.xml*, used by GraniteDS to establish communication between Java & Flex.

I need this kind of configuration, in order to be able to change **servername**, **serverport** and **security credentials** defined in *factories* node without to rebuild the entire application.

Thanks in advance
Mat

Comment: Do you mean externalize from your compiled Flex app?  Or externalize from the server?  sevices-config.xml files are usually already external; unless you want to change the servername/port/etc at runtime.

Comment: services-config.xml is not in the swf but it's included in .war file. I want to externalize from the war and put it in a configuration directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to implement what i'd like by overwritting the **EjbServiceFactory** with a **CustomEjbServiceFactory** based on the EjbServiceFactory but retrieving all information for InitialContext from a properties file in a specific directory and not from the default services-config.xml

See [EjbServiceFactory.java](https://github.com/graniteds/graniteds/blob/master/core/org/granite/messaging/service/EjbServiceFactory.java)